# facebook font-awsom icon is not showing in my button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, font-awesome, glyphicons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDs5j.jpg)I am trying to use facebook font awsm icon using this code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Although I am giving the cdn path but still the icon is not showing. 
But If I use any bootstrap icon then icon is showing over there. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle, question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style and you good to go

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/v08wrbx2/

Comment: Hey Parish .. I am adding the cdn but this icon is not coming.. m attaching the screenshot.

Comment: have u changed `color` property of `.fa-facebook`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with others icons. If the only icons that doesn't work are social logos (facebook, twitter...), then maybe It's because of AdBlock Plus. Make sure do desactivate it in the page you want, or look at your AdBlock filter preferences and uncheck "Fanboy's Social Blocking List".